# Scala: Exception Pattern Matching

Tags: scala

I need to define an `Exception` that provides context information... and this information is stored in a `Map`. To avoid wrong key names, I've defined the following `Enumeration`:

```
object ContextValueName extends Enumeration {

  type ContextValueName = Value

  val Value1 = Value("Value1")
  val Value2 = Value("Value2")
  val ValueN = Value("ValueN")

  implicit def toString(name: ContextValueName) = name.toString
}
```

This is the `Exception` code:

```
import ContextValueName._

trait MyException extends RuntimeException {

  val errorCode: Int
  val contextValues: Map[ContextValueName, Option[String]]
}

object MyException {

  def apply(
    message: String, _errorCode: Int, _contextValues: Map[ContextValueName, Option[String]]
  ): MyException = new RuntimeException(message) with MyException {
    val errorCode: Int = _errorCode
    val contextValues: Map[ContextValueName, Option[String]] = _contextValues.withDefault(_ => None)
  }

  def unapply(exception: MyException) = {
    if (exception eq null) None
    else Some((
      exception.errorCode,
      exception.contextValues
    ))
  }
}
```

And finally here is how I handle exceptions of type `MyException`:

```
callService("myService").map { result =>
  ...
}.recover {
  case e@MyException(1, contextValues) =>
    Logger.debug(s"error invoking myService: ${contextValues(Value1).get}")
  case NonFatal(e) =>
    Logger.error(s"unhandled error: ${e.getMessage}")
}
```

The problem is that the first `case` statement is never executed even if the thrown exception is like `MyException(1, Map(Value1 -> "too busy"))`, and execution always falls in the last `case` statement. Am I missing something?

Comment: Not relevant (I hope) but the implicit called toString is an unnecessary overload. Maybe call it `to string` in backquotes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use Try, which is supposed to be a bit more natural for Scala.

```
Try {
   callService("myService")
} match {
  case Success(s) => // something you do when you succeed
  case Failure(ex) => ex match {
    case ex@MyException(1, contextValues) =>
      Logger.debug(s"error invoking myService: ${contextValues(Value1).get}")
    case NonFatal(ex) =>
      Logger.error(s"unhandled error: ${ex.getMessage}")
  }
}
```

Comment: Usual to `case Failure(MyException(1, vs))`.

Answer (score 0):

Small consolation, but FWIW, IWFM.

```
object Test extends App {
    import util._
    val res = Try (throw MyException("help", 1, Map(Value1 -> Option("bad")))) recover {
      case e@MyException(1, vals) => vals
    }
    Console println res

    import concurrent._
    import duration.Duration._
    import ExecutionContext.Implicits._
    val f = Future (throw MyException("help", 1, Map(Value1 -> Option("bad")))) recover {
      case e@MyException(1, vals) => vals
    }
    Console println Await.result(f, Inf)
}
```